# add new column in default contacts content provider of android

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I have requirement to add new column in default contacts table provided by android so can I do that .I just want to add a new value in that column if it is added from my application.So please tell me if it is possible  .

Edit:My aim is to add data in defaults contacts table  programatically so that it will also be visible when user opens default phonebook.[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do that ??

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ No not now.I have searched over it but dint get post related to it.Now I am going to understand contacts table structure.May be that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not possible.
Though it technically is, the end result will not be desirable:

1. It would need root obviously. You can't modify the data of other apps without root.
2. You would need to find where the actual SQLite database file is located, open that, modify it.
3. Would the contacts app even work after this modification? Doubtful.
4. Would this modification persist? Doubtful.

Why not make the association some other way? Store whatever value you have with an identifuer from the contacts database.

Comment: "Why not make the association some other way? Store whatever value you have with an identifuer from the contacts db."Please describe it .

Comment: save the contact id and whatever data wanted to stick in the contacts db in an db in your own app.

Comment: but i want to provide that data out of application also.So is there any other option for that?

Comment: create a contentprovider that serves up whatever data you are wanting. Your question is now getting away from your main question, i would ask this separately. Also, please consider marking this one as accepted as it answered your stated question.

Comment: see I want to add a coplumn in contacts table and add my data in that,so that user can alos get that data in his default phonebook also.

Comment: the default phone book has no way of displaying that data though. I dont think that you have fully thought through your idea. sounds like you need to create a whole custom contacts app or something to achieve wehat you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59279/discussion-between-bansal-sneha-and-r2doesinc).